# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}\:$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}$$

if we can find sum of this series then we can evaluate limit

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{(3)1!}+ \frac{1}{(4)2!}+\frac{1}{(5)3!}+ .... \frac{1}{(n+2)n!}
\end{equation*}

How we can find sum of this series

Answer (score 17):

$$\sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n+1)}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa They *are* everywhere!

Comment: Do we need to mention that the series is absolutely convergent?  Note: the rearrangement into two series requires commutativity.  Conditionally convergent series are **not** required to be commutative.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint.** Using 
$$
\int_0^1x^{r+1}dx=\frac1{r+2}
$$ you may write
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r!}\int_0^1x^{r+1}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r!}x^{r+1}dx=\int_0^1x(e^x-1)dx
$$ giving

> $$
> \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}=\frac12.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

First find $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}$ for this let

Tr( rth term ) = $\frac{1}{(r+2)r!}$ or tn(nth term ) = $\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}$

Now simplyfying tn ..

$\frac{n+1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!}$

$\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$

now let $n+1=a_1+a_2(n+2) $and find value of $a_1$ and $a_2 $that is $a_1$=-1 and $a_2 $=1  ,

we get tn = $\frac{a_1+a_2(n+2)}{(n+2)!}$

or

tn=$\frac{1}{(n+2)!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

put value of n=1,2,3,4,.... and add all term you will get sum =$\frac{1}{2}$

now , limit can we evaluated easily that is $\frac{1}{2}$